# More than one line, in single loop (System.Windows.Shapes) C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, line

I am working on my own graph drawing application. I have got the graph and the updating mechanisme working like i want to. Now I am trying to draw a grid, So i need some lines on the axis of my graph, so I came up with this little loop:

```
        Gridx = new Line();

        while (x <= _XAxisSize)
        {

            gridx.X1 = x; 
            gridx.X2 = x;
            gridx.Y1 = _YAxisSize - 20;
            gridx.Y2 = _YAxisSize + 20;

            x = x + XgridSize;

            gridx.UpdateLayout();
        }
```

This doesn't work, because it only draws one line (the last point of the loop). So i need to draw multiple lines on that axes. How dow i accomplish something like that, using either the line() from the system.Windows.Shapes library, or any other shape in that library

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple lines, you need to create multiple lines:

```
while (x <= _XAxisSize)
{
    var gridx = new Line();

    gridx.X1 = x; 
    gridx.X2 = x;
    gridx.Y1 = _YAxisSize - 20;
    gridx.Y2 = _YAxisSize + 20;

   //need to add gridx to your view here

    x = x + XgridSize;
}
```

However, for such static lines you might be better off looking at using a `GeometryDrawing` which has much less overhead than the `Line` shape. See [here](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/WPF-Shapes-vs-WPF-Geometries.aspx) for details about the differences.